# aws amplify cli installation error on windows

Tags: node.js, amazon-web-services, npm, axios, aws-amplify

I'm trying to install aws amplify cli on windows.
Having stuck on the below screen while run "npm install -g @aws-amplify/cli" command.

Can anyone help me on this?

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Here is what worked for me -
Delete `.amplify` folder from `C:\Users\<user_name>`

And then run `curl -sL https://aws-amplify.github.io/amplify-cli/install-win -o install.cmd && install.cmd`